# D3. Load SVG files and show only one at a time. Fading/Replacing issue

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I would like to load *svg* files into one *div* (or whatever) and I even can do it successfully [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qcrynj01/):

```
var div_svg = d3.select("div#example");

svg1 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg";
svg2 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg";

var createSvg = function(dataset) {
   d3.xml(dataset)
   .mimeType("image/svg+xml")
   .get(function(error, xml) {
      if (error) throw error;
      div_svg.node().append(xml.documentElement);
   });
}

update = function(dataset) {
    div_svg.select('svg')
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .remove();
    createSvg(dataset)
}

createSvg(svg1);
d3.select("#one").on("click", function() { update(svg1); });
d3.select("#two").on("click", function() { update(svg2); });
```

But I have some issues:

1. Once you are about to choose another *svg* file, the first one fades off as it should, but another one stacks below until previous disappear at all. How can I replace one svg with another smoothly?
2. If I continue clicking on svg "button" quickly, more than one graph appear in the the div. I could make a dirty fix, just checking that the svg has been rendered already, but I would like to figure out how to fix this asynchronous update issue in a better way.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

so what i would do: wait after your have loaded your svg to do the transition that fade the prvious svg, then wait for the transition to finish, remove the old one, add the new one and fade it in :

```
var createSvg = function(dataset) {
    d3.xml(dataset)
            .mimeType("image/svg+xml")
            .get(function(error, xml) {
                d3.select("#example")
                        .select('svg')
                        .style("opacity", 1)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(200)
                        .style("opacity", 0);

                setTimeout(function(){
                    d3.select("#example")
                            .select('svg').remove();

                    div_svg.node().append(xml.documentElement);

                    d3.select("#example")
                            .selectAll('svg')   .select('svg')
                            .style("opacity", 0)
                            .transition()
                            .duration(200)
                            .style("opacity", 1);
                }, 200);

                if (error) throw error;
            });
};

update = function(dataset) {
    createSvg(dataset)
};
```